# Google test: strange behaviour when testing C code

Tags: c, googletest

I`m trying to test my C code by using Google test(never worked with it before) but looks like it thinks that I wanna test C++ code

```
23: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
     str->data = malloc(buf_size + 1);
33: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
         char *new_begin = malloc(buf_size + 1);
```

My testing file (if instead of including source file I include header it fails during testing (or maybe even before)

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
extern "C" {
#include "../lib/scr/c_string.c"
}
```

All in all, I just changed code for

```
str->data = (char*)malloc(buf_size + 1);
```

as it works on C++. Thankfully, nothing crashed :)

Comment: `str->data = malloc(buf_size + 1);` This works as-is in C, but requires a cast in C++. It sounds like you are compiling a C file as C++, instead. Why `#include "../lib/scr/c_string.c"`, and why "*test my C code*" using a `.cpp` file?

Comment: I am trying to include my C file as in some examples that I saw on the Internet.
what do you mean by using cpp? As far as I know, I can`t create C file for google test.

Comment: Assuming `LibTests.cpp` is your file, it gets compiled as C++ because `.cpp` is the default extension for C++ files. But you `#include` plain C code in it, which will not compile as C++ because C is a (related but) different language. This causes compilation to fail, with the errors you quoted.

Comment: Hmm, okay you are right. I should find some other way to test my code. Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extern "C" does not turn the included source code into C it specifies a linkage convention to use for the declarations which occur within the block you have included your file into.

In other words, your C file contents are being copied into a C++ source file, and compiled as C++, with C linking conventions.